# Gravar valores sempre for que adicionado uma nova linha através de trigger

Tags: oracle, trigger

Preciso de ajuda para resolver um problema, tentei do meio jeito, mas não esta dando certo.

Tenho duas tabela a qual tenho de realizar esta actividade e crie um `trigger` chamado `trg_line_total` para gravar o valor de `line_total` na tabela `LINE` sempre que for adicionada uma nova linha em `LINE`.

O valor de `LINE_TOTAL` é o produto dos valores de `LINE_UNITS`(Unidade do produto da linha) e `LINE_PRICE`(Preço do produto da linha)

```
CREATE TABLE INVOICE( 
  INV_NUMBER number primary key, 
  INV_DATE date default SYSDATE not null,
  INV_SUBTOTAL NUMBER(9,2)DEFAULT 0.00, 
  INV_TAX NUMBER(9,2)DEFAULT 0.00, 
  INV_TOTAL NUMBER(9,2)DEFAULT 0.00, 
 CONSTRAINT INV_CK1 CHECK(INV_DATE>TO_DATE('01-JAN-2008','DD-MON-YYYY')));

CREATE TABLE LINE( 
  INV_NUMBER number not null, 
  LINE_NUMBER number not null,
  LINE_UNITS Number default 0 not null, 
  LINE_PRICE number(9,2) default 0.00 not null, 
  LINE_TOTALE number(9,2) default 0.00 not null, 
  primary key(INV_NUMBER,LINE_NUMBER),
  foreign key(INV_NUMBER)references INVOICE on delete cascade);

CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER trg_line_total
  AFTER INSERT ON line
  FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
  total  line.line_totale%TYPE;
  codigo line.inv_number%TYPE;
BEGIN
  SELECT inv_number
    INTO codigo
    FROM invoice
   WHERE inv_number = :new.inv_number;
  total := :new.line_units * :new.line_price;
  UPDATE line
     SET line_totale = line_totale + total
   WHERE inv_number = codigo;
END;
```

Comment: Pesquisa sobre `trigger mutant` que ira te ajudar, pois está tentando alterar um registro da própria tabela que está sendo incluído.

Comment: Talvez uma trigger de STATEMENT e com uso de Constarint DEFERRABLE

Answer (score 0):

Pelo que entendi o problema é você atualizar a LINE_TOTAL somando  o valor antigo com o novo inserido. Tipo assim, teste se este código resolveria seu problema. Esse select que você dá é algo ambiguo, você utiliza ele e depois no where do update é a mesma coisa que você usar só a chamada dele.

Faça o teste e avise como comportou e se resolveu.

```
create or replace TRIGGER trg_line_total AFTER INSERT ON LINE
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    update LINE
   set LINE_TOTAL = :old.LINE_TOTAL + (:new.LINE_UNITS * :new.LINE_PRICE);
   where INV_NUMBER = :new.INV_NUMBER;
END;
```

Faça o teste no        where INV_NUMBER = :new.INV_NUMBER * :new.;
ou        where INV_NUMBER = :old.INV_NUMBER;

Comment: Boa Noite Gustavo

Comment: SQL Error: ORA-04091: table BD.LINE is mutating, trigger/function may not see it
INSERT INTO LINE(INV_NUMBER,LINE_NUMBER,LINE_UNITS,LINE_PRICE)VALUES(INV_INVOICE_SEQ.NEXTVAL,1,1,10)
Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-04091: table BD.LINE is mutating, trigger/function may not see it
ORA-06512: at "BD.TRG_LINE_TOTAL", line 2

Comment: Existe uma trigger utilizando a tabela LINE, desabilita ela e faça o teste. Sou inciante e tive o mesmo problema de mutating, faça o seguinte teste a mão. Desabilite a triger trg_line_total e faça o seguinte. 
ALTER TRIGGER LINE_TRG DISABLE;
ALTER TRIGGER trg_line_total  ENABLE;
'CODIGO DO INSERT' 
ALTER TRIGGER LINE_TRG ENABLE;
ALTER TRIGGER trg_line_total  DISABLE;

Este problema o corre porque duas triggers estão tentando acessar ao mesmo tempo. Tive que fazer essa "gambiarra" de habilitações e desabilitações de triggers. No caso igual o cara ali em cima disse de resolver o mutating

Comment: Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-02291: integrity constraint (BD.SYS_C007848) violated - parent key not found
02291. 00000 - "integrity constraint (%s.%s) violated - parent key not found" 
*Cause:    A foreign key value has no matching primary key value.
*Action:   Delete the foreign key or add a matching primary key.

Comment: Vish amigo, não sei não heim, vou deixar em aberto. Esse erro também me ajuda. Abs.

Answer (score 0):

```
create or replace TRIGGER trg_line_total AFTER INSERT ON LINE 
-- STATEMENT NAO "EACH ROW"
BEGIN
    --MONTA UM CURSOR (RTOTAL) PARA TOTALIZAR OS VALORES 
    for RTOTAL in (SELECT line.inv_number , SUM(line_units * :new.line_price) TOTAL
              FROM invoice , line
              WHERE invoice.inv_number = line.inv_number
              GROUP BY line.inv_number)
    LOOP    
        -- ATUALIZA AS LINHAS COM OS TOTAIS APURADOS (SE O VALOR FOR DIFERENTE)   
        UPDATE line
               SET line_total = RTOTAL .total
        WHERE inv_number = RTOTAL.inv_number
        AND   line_total <> RTOTAL.total;
    END LOOP;   
END;
```

Creio que isto resolva por trigger , será disparada após o fim da instrução , verifica saldo divergentes e atualiza , a performance deve (quase com certeza) ficar ruim mas creio que vala o teste.
Existe alguma razão para ter este total em cada linha de detalhe ? Uma outra solução de obrter iso e´por uma sql que faça um "running total" usando funções analíticas (OVER) , mas faça o teste desta minha "solução".

Comment: sim, a cada instante que se adiciona um produto na line deve-se saber o total. Qual o papel de r e R e onde termina o for descupe so aprendiz

Comment: Comentei na resposta. Ainda acho que o melhor é revisar o modelo , uma outra tabela totalizadora , totalizar por select etc.